# Create a column with an if condition in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

i am not sure if i could use conditional statement while creating new columns.

Code:

```
create table Employees(
Emp_ID int primary key identity (1,1),
Hours_worked int,
Rate int default '')
```

/*Now here in default value i want to set different rates depending upon hours worked. like if hour worked is greater than 8 then rate is 300, if hours worked is less than 8 hour the rate is 200.) How to write this as a `Default` value in sql server 2008.

**My second question is:**

Why i get error if i write like this,

```
create table tbl_1(
col_1 varchar(max) unique
)
```

The error is

```
Column 'col_1' in table 'tbl_1' is of a type that is invalid for use as a key column in an index.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
```

Regards
Waqar

Comment: Your first question. You don't. A default is a default value for a column. It is not conditional. Your second question, why would you think you should use unique on a varchar(max)? That doesn't make any sense. You could use unique if the varchar has a limit but anything more than a few characters is ridiculous anyway.

Comment: ok i get it. but is there any way i could add condition to the rates.yes it is ridiculous but what's the reason behind this error?

Comment: The reason is that an index size is 900 bytes and a varchar(max) can take a lot more than that.

Comment: Thanks @AllanS.Hansen. Beat me to it.

Comment: ok i get it. my first question: is there any way i could add condition to the rates column.

Comment: @WaqarAdilMughal you cant really dynamically set the default value for a column. You could always write a sql statement that updates that values conditionally but that wouldn't be considered a default value. A default value is added if none is given.

Comment: Is there any way i could add condition to the rates, You could make the column a computed column and not allow a user variance... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014108/function-based-index-in-sql-server-2005

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/135230). **Why** do you want to add a condition to a default? What do you think that is going to win you?

Comment: @DourHighArch I am betting its done so that its one column that doesn't need to be added to any insert/update and computed automatically.

Comment: @DourHighArch I used the same trick in MS excel where i made a Conditional column. so i thought it may be possibe in sqlserver. logixologist is absolutely right. i really meant that.

Comment: How can an integer be a string? Do you also want to default your datetime columns to `'never'`?

Comment: @AaronBertrand i dont understand your point.. I think datatype is same which is integer.  Your qustion:"Do you also want to default your datetime columns to 'never'? – " How datetime datatype can be a string??

Comment: You have `int default ''` <--- `''` is an empty string, not an integer. Did you mean 0 or NULL?

Comment: @AaronBertrand if datatype is int and value of Default is '' then the value will be 0 automatically and if datatype is varchar then the default value will be 'space'.. I used, '' as an example..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use COMPUTED Column, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx

```
create table Employees(
Emp_ID int primary key identity (1,1),
Hours_worked int,
Rate   as (case when Hours_worked > 8 then 300  else 200 end) persisted )
```

Answer (score 1):

The default value cannot refer to any other column names. So the "default" value of Rate won't know the value of Hours_worked. You could handle it with a trigger or whatever is doing the actual inserting could contain this logic.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173565(v=sql.100).aspx

You cannot but a `UNIQUE` constraint on a `VARCHAR(MAX)` field.

Comment: @rajesh answered this perfectly.