# Substring function in where clause slowing the query

Tags: sql-server

I have a query which contains following condition in `where` clause. This condition is slowing the output of query by almost 1 min.

```
where B.SysStatus=substring(B.StatusCode,1,CHARINDEX('-',B.StatusCode)-1)
```

Please suggest any other alternative which will give faster output.

Comment: I'm not sure it will help but try `where B.StatusCode LIKE B.SysStatus+'%' AND B.SysStatus=substring(B.StatusCode,1,CHARINDEX('-',B.StatusCode)-1)`

Comment: FilterStatus is result of a user defined function in select query like.select dbo.GetFilterStatus( params) as FilterStatus,

Comment: Do you mean SysStatus saying FilterStatus? if it is a calculated column, probably a good idea is to show its code.

Comment: I am sorry. UDF dbo.GetFilterStatus( params) returns StatusCode

Comment: And what is inside of GetFilterStatus?

Comment: Your first solution helped me a little.Reduced the query time by 20 secs.Thanks Dmitry.

Answer (score 3):

I think what Thilo is trying to say is that you should add a persisted computed column into your table and index it, and then use it in the search criteria.

Either by doing just the statuscode with something like this:

```
alter table YourTable 
add NewColumnName as 
  substring(StatusCode,1,CHARINDEX('-',StatusCode)-1) persisted
```

Or the comparison:

```
alter table YourTable
add NewColumnName as 
  case when SysStatus = substring(StatusCode,1,CHARINDEX('-',StatusCode)-1)
  then 1 else 0 end persisted
```

Which is better depends on the other usage, if you'll need to have the first part of the column in other clauses too, then that's more useful but if you always just need to compare the equality to SysStatus, then I would create the latter. You could also think about filtered indexes, if the matches are rare.

Answer (score 0):

That computation probably prevents efficient index access paths.

You could build a "functional index" on the computed column value or the whole equality condition. If the database does not offer that kind of index, denormalize a bit and store the substring/flag in a second column.

In SQL-Server, you should [be able to do something like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014108/function-based-index-in-sql-server-2005)

```
ALTER TABLE b ADD COLUMN match_status_code 
  AS CASE WHEN 
    sys_status = substring(StatusCode,1,CHARINDEX('-',StatusCode)-1)
  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

and then index that.

Comment: how can i build functional index on  computed column value or the whole equality condition